# Vue js gallery image with pagination

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, pagination

So I'm trying a 3x3 grid image view with pagination on vue my project where I display the image by doing an HTTP request

I have been searching on youtube and google all day long but I don't find any tutorial or documentation that I can follow.
is there any source code/youtube tutorial to make this thing? I'm not asking you to code for me or answering this question with code, but I need a resource to learn how to code this thing

is there any external library that I can use? because it seems hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice tutorial for creating a pagination component with Vue:
https://css-tricks.com/creating-a-reusable-pagination-component-in-vue/

For styling the 3x3, you could use either [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [grid layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

If you are doing pagination in the front-end (i.e. has a big array directly loaded in the client), your task is to break it down in pages so it only loads a chunk of it at a time. If pagination is happening on the back-end, you need to update your local instance per server call and keep track of where you are and if the server has more items.

Unfortunately, there aren't much shortcuts to learning pagination until you implement it hands-on and learn from it.